# Cannot create symlink from /var/tmp to /tmp. Cannot delete /var/tmp - CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, rhel7, tmp

I cannot delete /var/tmp as it says,

```
#  rm -Rf /var/tmp
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/tmp’: Device or resource busy
```

Because of this, I cannot create a symbolic link from /var/tmp to /tmp.

How can I achieve this ?

**Output of df**

```
| Filesystem | 1K-blocks | Used    | Available | Use% | Mounted        |
|------------|:---------:|---------|-----------|------|----------------|
| /dev/sda1  | 31443968  | 1693220 | 29750748  | 6%   | /              |
| devtmpfs   | 862096    | 0       | 862096    | 0%   | /dev           |
| tmpfs      | 868712    | 0       | 868712    | 0%   | /dev/shm       |
| tmpfs      | 868712    | 8408    | 860304    | 1%   | /run           |
| tmpfs      | 868712    | 0       | 868712    | 0%   | /sys/fs/cgroup | 
| tmpfs      | 173744    | 0       | 173744    | 0%   | /run/user/1000 |
| /dev/loop0 | 3871532   | 15624   | 3639524   | 1%   | /tmp           |
```

**Output of mount**

> sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
>   proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) devtmpfs on
>   /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=862096k,nr_inodes=215524
>   ,mode=755) securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relat
>   ime) tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel) devpts on
>   /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=62
>   0,ptmxmode=000) tmpfs on /run type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755) tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs
>   (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755) cgroup on
>   /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xa
>   ttr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
>   pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blki
>   o) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu
>   set) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatim
>   e,cpuacct,cpu) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mem
>   ory) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,de
>   vices) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hu
>   getlb) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,re
>   latime,net_prio,net_cls) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type
>   cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
>   ,perf_event) cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids) cgroup on
>   /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,fr
>   eezer) configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
>   /dev/sda1 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
>   selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime) systemd-1 on
>   /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,time
>   out=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct) hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type
>   hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel) mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue
>   (rw,relatime,seclabel) debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs
>   (rw,relatime) /home/mntTmp on /tmp type ext4
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,data=or
>   dered) tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=173744k,
>   mode=700) tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=17374
>   4k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1001)

Comment: `umount /var/tmp` then comment out /var/tmp in /etc/fstab.

Comment: /var/tmp isn't mounted. I've pasted the result of df already.

Comment: Please paste the output of the `mount` command

Comment: I updated main question. I'm sorry if it isn't organized, but I hope you can check what you need

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output provided, /var/tmp is mounted under / (root) filesystem. /tmp filesystem is your swap. Not sure why you need to symlink swap to /var/tmp.

Comment: I'm trying to follow https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/linux/CIS_CentOS_Linux_7_Benchmark_v1.1.0.pdf and it suggest that "1.1.6 Bind Mount the /var/tmp directory to /tmp (Scored)".